# Setting values of a list to a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filepath

**Scenario:** I have 2 lists, one is a list of strings with names, the other is a list of dataframes with varied content. I am trying to put the values from the first list into the second.

**Data Example:**

```
list1 = ['jan18', 'feb18', 'mar18', 'apr18', 'may18']
```

List two is a list of dataframes with the following structure:

```
DF1_LIST2:
row1      row2      row3    row4
           5         55      12
           3         51      11
           3         52      11
           9         59      11

DF2_LIST2:
row1      row2      row3    row4
           9         91      7
           5         1       23
           3         24      56
           9         68      21
```

My objective is to add the first element of list1 to all cells in the first column of the first dataframe of list2; then the second element of list2 to all cells of the first column of the second dataframe of list 2, and so on. The output would be something like:

```
DF1_LIST2:
row1      row2      row3    row4
jan18      5         55      12
jan18      3         51      11
jan18      3         52      11
jan18      9         59      11

DF2_LIST2:
row1      row2      row3    row4
feb18      9         91      7
feb18      5         1       23
feb18      3         24      56
feb18      9         68      21
```

What I got so far was trying to establish a triple for loop, the first iterates over items of list1, the second over dataframes of list2 and the third over rows of each dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import glob

# Get File Names
mypath = "//DGMS/Desktop/uploaded"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

# Get dates
onlyfiles = [name.split("_")[0] for name in onlyfiles]    
df_of_names = pd.DataFrame(onlyfiles) 

# Get File Contents
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(mypath, "*.xls*"))
contentdataframes = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_files]

for dfs in contentdataframes:
dfs.insert(0,"date*","")
dfs.insert(1,"apply*","")

for date in onlyfiles:  
     for dfs in contentdataframes:  
        for row in dfs.itertuples(index=True):
            dfs.set_value(row,0,date)
```

This gives me an error, I believe because of the header column, which still counts as a normal row, not an index.

**Question:** Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: There is difference between `onlyfiles` and `all_files` ?

Comment: Is possible extract dates from `all_files` ?

Comment: @jezrael Only files retrieves the list without the file path, just the names. All_files also include the path, for example: //DGMS/Desktop/uploaded\iteration5_tes3_Jun.xlsx

Comment: hmmm, is possible add sample of `all_files` ? I think `onlyfiles` are not necessary (but maybe I am wrong)

Comment: @jezrael onlyfiles would be iteration5_tes3_Jun.xlsx where I want just the value before the first underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for add new column in each `DataFrame`:

```
d = [pd.read_excel(f).assign(row1=os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0])
     for f in all_files]
```

EDIT:

If want working with columns and `.assign` with multiple columns is worse readable, is possible use `loop` for process each `DataFrame` and last append to `list`:

```
contentdataframes = []
for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    df['col1'] = 10
    df['col2'] = 'string1'
    df['row1'] = os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0]
    contentdataframes.append(df)
```

Comment: One thing I forgot in my initial code: before I entered the loops, I added 2 columns to each dataframe (which are the ones to be filled with the data from list 1). Is there a way to add a column before assigning the data?

Comment: I think is possible use `.assign(row1=os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0].split('_')[0], col1=1, col2='string1')`

Comment: i think in assign is possible add multiple new columns

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the filename from the full path via [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). Then wrap in a list comprehension with [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
import os

def extract_name(x):
    return os.path.splitext(fp)[0].split('_')[0]

dfs = [pd.read_excel(fp).assign(row1=extract_name(fp)) for fp in all_files]
```

Comment: two questions: what would be fp in this case and how can I set the path?

Comment: Each `fp` is an item in your list `all_files`. The paths are already calculated in the items of `all_files` via your `glob.glob` call.

Comment: Just tried it, it adds a row at the end of each dataframe with the full file path, not just the part of the filename (withouth the path) before the underscore. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: `.assign` adds a new column, not a new row. You can split by `_`, see update.